# Merge 2 wix libraries

Tags: wix

Is it possible to merge two wix libraries into one?

Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an ad hoc tool to merge two wixlib into one. But you can easily achieve the same effect by slightly changing your build script.

I suppose you have a set of wixobj files you pass to lit.exe to create wixlib_1, and you also have another set of wixobj files to create wixlib_2. If that's the case, then you can unite these sets and pass it to lit.exe once to have a single wixlib.

This is true if you owe the authoring source code, or at least have access to wixobj files. Otherwise, if it is "third-party" wixlibs, then why bothering? :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you'd want to do that but lit.exe can. Feed it any combination of .wixobjs or .wixlibs and it should create a new .wixlib of the content.